# Second order differential, getting 0 on the left side

Tags: calculus, differential

If I have $$y''+y'-6y = e^{2x}$$

and I choose $$Ce^{2x}$$ as my guess

then when computing the left side I get zero, what do I do to prevent this?

Comment: The next thing to try would be $Cxe^{2x}$.

Comment: You should type mathematics using Mathjax notation, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . I've done it for you this time

Comment: Do you know D operator?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Is the x going to be in my solution then? Or should I just use Cxe to find the C and then replace Cxe^2x to Ce^2x?

Comment: To @frigolit_tarzan: Check this website to learn how to solve Second Order Linear Nonhomogeneous Differential Equations with Constant Coefficients: https://www.math24.net/second-order-linear-nonhomogeneous-differential-equations-constant-coefficients/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "associated homogeneous equation", y''+ y'- 6y= 0 has characteristic equation $r^2+ r- 6= (r+ 3)(r- 2)= 0$ so that r= 2 and -3. That is, the general solution to the associated homogeneous equation is $Ae^{2x}+ Be^{-3x}$.   Since $e^{2x}$ satisfies the associated homogeneous equation, $Ce^{2x}$ cannot give $e^{2x}$ for any C.  The standard thing to try instead is to use $y= Cxe^{2x}$.  That way, using the product rule to differentiate you will have a part where you have differentiated the "$e^{2x}$", which will give 0, and a part where you have differentiated "x".

With $y= Cxe^{2x}$, $y'= Ce^{2x}+ 2Cxe^{2x}$ and $y''= 2Ce^{2x}+ 2Ce^{2x}+ 4xe^{2x}=
4Ce^{2x}+ 4Cxe^{2x}$ so that $y''+ y'- 6y= 4Ce^{2x}+ 4Cxe^{2x}+ Ce^{2x}+ 2Cxe^{2x}- 6Cxe^{2x}= 5Ce^{2x}= e^{2x}$.  Notice that the "$Cxe^{2x}$ terms cancelled.  $Cxe^{2x}$ satisfies the equation if C= 1/5.

What textbook are you using?  Every Differential Equations text that I have seen covers this in detail.

Comment: accidental post.